# xml specific tag transformation using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

**my input xml file:**

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
     <document form='def'>
    <item name="aaa">
        <text>value1</text>
      </item>
     <item name="bbb">
        <text>value2</text>
      </item>
    </document>
```

**the required xml file as output:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<document form='def'>             
    <CRSCINPUT>
        <aaa>
            value1
        </aaa>
    </CRSCINPUT>
</document>
```

please provide the xslt file to convert it.

I just want to change the specific tag with the name "aaa" other tags will remain the same.

Comment: "*change the specific tag with the name "aaa" other tags will remain the same*" That's not what your output shows.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the case, try the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

            <!-- apply an identity template --> 
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

            <!-- then match the node that you want to change -->
    <xsl:template match="item[@name='aaa']">
        <CRSCINPUT>
            <xsl:element name="{@name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </CRSCINPUT>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document form="def">
   <CRSCINPUT>
      <aaa>value1</aaa>
   </CRSCINPUT>
   <item name="bbb">
      <text>value2</text>
   </item>
</document>
```